# How do up update the r600 ATI graphics driver in 14.04?

Tags: 14.04, drivers, ati, google-chrome

I am hitting regular issues with Google Chrome failing.

I filed a bug against it and their developers diagnosed it as being a problem in the r600 graphics driver that was installed with 14.04. You can see that bug report and conversation here:

https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=467821

OK... so I filed a bug against the driver, and was told that the one I am running is over a year old and many bugs have been fixed since then. That bug is here:

https://bugs.freedesktop.org/show_bug.cgi?id=89619

I need Chrome to not die multiple times a day.

How do I update my device driver in 14.04 to the latest version - without too much magic, please, if possible - so I can get Chrome to work reliably?

Thank you!